# How to use Spring with I18n?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf

I've my project on github : https://github.com/QuentinVaut/JavaquariumEE

I've follow many tutorial who say different things and I tried to implement the solutions found in tutorials but nothing wrong, I understand why.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my project and explain me ?

One of many tutorials and Github sample :

http://memorynotfound.com/spring-mvc-internationalization-i18n-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application.properties, I added this line :

```
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages
spring.messages.cache-seconds=-1
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
```

You can remove the MessageSource bean with this.

Before I use

```
 <spring:message code="javaquarium.welcome" text="default text" />
```

But I've thymleaf need this line :

```
<h1 th:text="#{javaquarium.welcome}"></h1>
```

Now message from messages.properties show correctly.

Answer (score 8):

I had a cursory look over that tutorial. Here is how I would do it:

First Configure it:

Create a Bean in the configuration class that returns the MessageSource
implementation.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() //The bean must be named messageSource.
{
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource =
new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setCacheSeconds(-1); //cache time in seconds was set to -1. This disables reloading and makes the message source cache messages forever (until the JVM restarts).
messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
messageSource.setBasenames(
"/WEB-INF/i18n/messages", "/WEB-INF/i18n/errors"); //the message source is configured with the basenames /WEB-INF/i18n/messages and /WEB-INF/i18n/errors. This means that the message source will look for filenames like /WEB-INF/i18n/messages_en_US.properties, /WEB-INF/i18n/errors_fr_FR.properties
return messageSource;
}
```

Now create a bean that returns LocaleResolver:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() //The bean must be named localeResolver.
{
return new SessionLocaleResolver();
}
```

This makes the LocaleResolver available to any code executed by the DispatcherServlet. That means other non-view JSPs do not have access to the LocaleResolver. To take care of this problem, you can create a Filter and set it up like this:

```
private ServletContext servletContext;
private LocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();    
@Inject MessageSource messageSource;
...

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
request.setAttribute(
DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER_ATTRIBUTE, this.localeResolver
);
JstlUtils.exposeLocalizationContext(
(HttpServletRequest)request, this.messageSource
);
```

Now you need to configure Handler Interceptors:

You override the addInterceptors method of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in your configuration class to set up LocaleChangeInterceptor (or any other interceptor for that matter.):

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
{
super.addInterceptors(registry);
registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
}
```

Now you can simply use an @Injected LocaleResolver on your controller. You simply call setLocale on the resolver to update the current locale.

**Edit: More Specific Example:**

Say you have a simple controller that has this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Map<String, Object> model)
{
model.put("date", new Date());
model.put("alerts", 12);
model.put("numCritical", 0);
model.put("numImportant", 11);
model.put("numTrivial", 1);
return "home/index";
}
```

Then say you have messages_en_US.properties file under /WEB-INF/i18n/. This properties file contains messages localized for US English.

> title.alerts=Server Alerts Page
>
> alerts.current.date=Current Date and Time:
>
> number.alerts=There {0,choice,0#are no alerts|1#is one alert|1
>
> alert.details={0,choice,0#No alerts are|1#One alert is|1<{0,number,integer} > \
>   alerts are} critical. {1,choice,0#No alerts are|1#One alert is|1<{1,number,\
>   integer} alerts are} important. {2,choice,0#No alerts are|1#One alert \
>   is|1<{2,number,integer} alerts are} trivial.

Then, say that you have messages_es_MX.properties file under /WEB-INF/i18n/ and this file contains messages localized for
Mexican Spanish.

> title.alerts=Server Alertas Página
>
> alerts.current.date=Fecha y hora actual:
>   number.alerts={0,choice,0#No hay alertas|1#Hay una alerta|1
>
> alert.details={0,choice,0#No hay alertas son críticos|1#Una alerta es \
>   crítica|1<{0,number,integer} alertas son críticos}. \
>   {1,choice,0#No hay alertas son importantes|1#Una alerta es importante\
>   |1<{1,number,integer} alertas son importantes}. \
>   {2,choice,0#No hay alertas son triviales|1#Una alerta es trivial\
>   |1<{2,number,integer} alertas son triviales}.

Now, you need to use `<spring:message>` tag in your JSP to translate between English and Spanish. This is how your jsp page will look like:

```html
<spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape="true" />
<%--@elvariable id="date" type="java.util.Date"--%>
<%--@elvariable id="alerts" type="int"--%>
<%--@elvariable id="numCritical" type="int"--%>
<%--@elvariable id="numImportant" type="int"--%>
<%--@elvariable id="numTrivial" type="int"--%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><spring:message code="title.alerts" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2><spring:message code="title.alerts" /></h2>
<i><fmt:message key="alerts.current.date">
<fmt:param value="${date}" />
</fmt:message></i><br /><br />
<fmt:message key="number.alerts">
<fmt:param value="${alerts}" />
</fmt:message><c:if test="${alerts > 0}">
&nbsp;<spring:message code="alert.details">
<spring:argument value="${numCritical}" />
<spring:argument value="${numImportant}" />
<spring:argument value="${numTrivial}" />
</spring:message>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I implement doFilter method ? In my MvcConfig ?

Comment: No. That is a method that you override when you create a class that implements Filter Interface. We call that class Filter. You can look up how to set it up in your Spring Project. But you may not need to add a Filter at all. I just put it up there if some jsp doesn't show translation.

Comment: @QuentinV First try without creating a filter, if that doesn't work. Then yes look up how to create a filter and how to set it up in Spring MVC project. You will find many tutorials on that. But first try without it.

Comment: I've added your  messageSource, localeResolver and addInterceptor in my MvCConfig but the message in my view : UC01_especes javaquarium.welcome show nothing. Look on my Github link for the file MvcConfig.java

Comment: I just added more details in my answer. You can try them

Comment: I've folder i18n in my ressources dir. I use HTML file not JSP. I tried your solution but show : <spring:message code="title.alerts"/> in my title page and nothing show.

Comment: See. Spring tags will only work in a JSP file. JSP file is very simple to setup and configure. I doubt internationalization or translation would ever work in a HTML page. Still typing...

Comment: What JSP does it that any special tags that you add in addition to regular HTML tags, Server parses out all those special tags (and java code if JSP contains java code) and converts them to regular HTML and then sends it to your browser so your browser could render it. Therefore, my understanding is that translation will happen at the Server side. Then Server will push the translated stuff to the Client side (browser) to render it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136157/discussion-between-quentinv-and-faraz-durrani).

Comment: @QuentinV I see that you are using Thymeleaf. I have no idea how that works. It is definitely something similar to JSP, but I have zero training in it. Sorry